# Does SDWebImage support webp images without SDWebImageWebPCoder?

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage, webp

I was able to download and display Webp images without ***SDWebImageWebPCoder*** using ***SDWebImage 5.13.4***. So what is the purpose of SDWebImageWebPCoder?
Does ***SDWebImage*** already support Webp or am I wrong about something here?
How can I identify if Webp images are being downloaded to my app or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [ReadMe](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage#supported-image-formats):

> WebP format from iOS 14/macOS 11.0 via SDWebImageAWebPCoder. For lower firmware, use coder plugin SDWebImageWebPCoder

Google introduce the WebP format, and Apple decided later to support it, natively in `UIKit.framework`. So, natively, `UIImage(data: webpData)` works on iOS14 +.

Depending on which version of iOS you want to support for your App, you might need or not the `SDWebImageWebPCoder` plug-in lib, which will decode manually the WebP image raw data.

Comment: Do you know any native way to encode a UIImage in webp? Something like UIImage.pngData but for webp?

Comment: https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageWebPCoder seems to do both (decoding and encoding)